# Don't understand this AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
#archimedes spiral by rays

import math
import turtle

def spiral(t, a, b):
    diff=5
    number=500
    for i in range(number):
        t.penup()
        t.fd(a+b*i*diff*math.pi/180)
        t.pendown()
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(10)
        t.bk(10)
        t.rt(90)
        t.penup()
        t.bk(a+b*i*diff*math.pi/180)
        t.lt(diff)


bob=turtle.Turtle()
bob.speed(1000)

spiral(bob,0, 2)
```

The code gives an error message as follows:

```
RESTART: C:\Users\Manish Kumar\Desktop\TBN\repository\Competitive Programming\PYTHON\python scripts\archimedian_spiral.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manish Kumar\Desktop\TBN\repository\Competitive Programming\PYTHON\python scripts\archimedian_spiral.py", line 4, in <module>
    import turtle

File "C:\Users\Manish Kumar\Desktop\TBN\repository\Competitive Programming\PYTHON\python scripts\turtle.py", line 7, in <module>
    bob=turtle.Turtle()

AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'
>>>
```

I do not understand the error message. How can I make the code work? This code used to run smoothly some 3 to 4 months back.

Comment: The problem os resolved. I had created a python code and named it "turtle.py" by mistake. It was saved in the same folder as the above code. So, it was interfering with the turtle library

Answer (score 17):

Change your file name to something else like `turtle_something.py`. Your current name is conflicting with the `turtle` library.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is resolved. I made a mistake of creating a python script, naming it "turtle.py" and saving it in the same folder where i had kept this code. So, it was interfering with the turtle library