# Turning on turtle module in Python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have seen the installed turtledemo in Python extension. Clicking on this library function there open a graphic demo. But I can't import turtle in Visual Studio Code.

Python version was 3.3.1
Windows is 7-32 bit

It shows like

> 'module object has no attribute 'forward'

the code was:

```py
import turtle

turtle.forward(100)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Make sure your file name isn't `turtle.py`

Comment: Did you create the turtle?

Comment: @JonathanDrukker You don't need to create a turtle, there is a default one there.

Comment: A better dupe is [Don't understand this AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692691/dont-understand-this-attributeerror-module-turtle-has-no-attribute-turtle) or [AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480328/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-turtle-has-no-attribute-turtle)